# URL rewrite for image path - Multistore - .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, opencart-3

I have two store (Opencart3 - Multistore), and the second store the images is not taken from the first shop folder.

I would like to solve the following:
(for example)
`http://www.pce-hungary.hu/image/`
replace this image path (`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}` - I think...)
`https://shop.eurochrom.hu/image/`

How do I fix this under .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

These two lines had to be added and so good:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/image/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://shop.eurochrom.hu/image/%1 [R=302,NC]